# Does $\int_0^{a}q(x)[\alpha e^{\frac{-2\pi nix}{a}} + \beta e^{\frac{2\pi nix}{a}}]dx = 0 $ imply $q(x) = 0$ a.e?

Tags: integration, analysis

Let's assume that $q(x)$ is a piece-wise continuous real valued function that is periodic in $[0,a]$ for $a >0$.

For $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$,

does $\int_0^{a}q(x)[\alpha e^{\frac{-2\pi nix}{a}} + \beta e^{\frac{2\pi nix}{a}}]dx = 0 $ imply $q(x) = 0$ a.e?

Asking this to complete the proof of a long theorem, and not sure whether it's true and if so where to start to show this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $\alpha=\beta=1$. Your integral is $$ 2\int_0^aq(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{a}x\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

Take $$ q(x)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{a}x\right)$$